# make dynamic javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

can I create dynamic names for functions?  for example:

```
var name = 'test1';

function [name]() { ..... };
```

now I can call test1(); and this one runs the function name { ..... }; but with the [name] as test1, meaning that the function would run as

```
function test1() { ..... };
```

if I change the

```
var name = 'test2';
```

I can call the test2(); and this one runs the function name { ..... }; but with the [name] as test2, meaning that the function would run as

```
function test2() { ..... };
```

can that be done?

Comment: try `window[name] = function() {...}`

Comment: No, you can't. Not without an eval-like method. You can however define a function and store a reference to it in a dynamically named property on an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var test1 = function() {...};
var test2 = test1;

// now both of the following work

test1();
test2();
```

If you are working in a web browser you can also assign this function to a string value in the global object, `window`. Such as this

```
var originalFunction = function() {....};
var newName = "foo";
window[newName] = originalFunction;
// now both of the following work.
foo();
originalFunction();
```

Comment: Why the down vote with no comment? The code works and I believe this is what the OP was asking for. http://jsfiddle.net/4n1xowok/

Comment: Thank you David. I'll try that. ;By the way I wasn't the one downvoting it. )

Comment: it's more of a nuance problem, `window[thename] = function () {}` is not the same as `function thename () {}` in that in one case you're creating a named function, and in the other you're storing a reference to an anonymous function in a property. It's likely that that difference isn't important to the op though.